# ImageIcon won't display

Tags: java, imageicon, blackjack

Mac OSX
Netbeans
JAVA

Goal: BlackJack program... Im trying to get an imageIcon of a Playing Card to display in a JLabel

Logic: 
I have created some CARD objects with a method to return the imageIcon associated with it.
In my main GUI class it works if i create the new imageIcon specifying the file location -

```
    private void newGame(){

    String temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4;

    card1 = hand.dealHand();
    card2 = hand.dealHand();
    card3 = hand.dealHand();
    card4 = hand.dealHand();

    image1 = new ImageIcon();
    image1 = card1.getImage();


    //Creates DeckImage and Logo as JLabel and adds it to userPanel

    //image1 = new ImageIcon("/Users/philhunter/NetBeansProjects/PractingProgramming/src/Resources/1.png");


    card1Label = new JLabel(image1, JLabel.LEFT);
    userPanel.add(card1Label);

    card1Label.setText("");

}
```

The commented out line works fine and displays the imageIcon image but when I use the card1.getImage() method then the image does not display. The method is simply -

```
public ImageIcon getImage(){
    return this.image;
}
```

Also, in case you need it, here is the method that creates the CARD's from the DECK class -

```
private ImageIcon C1,C2, ... ,C52;
private ImageIcon[] imageArray= { C1,C2,...,C52 };
C1 = new ImageIcon("/Users/philhunter/NetBeansProjects/PractingProgramming/src/Resources/1.png");
...
C52 = new ImageIcon("/Users/philhunter/NetBeansProjects/PractingProgramming/src/Resources/52.png");

int SUITS = suit.length;
    int RANKS = rank.length;
    int N = SUITS * RANKS;

    //Creates a deck of 52 CARD objects
    theDeck = new CARD[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < RANKS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SUITS; j++) {
            //deck[SUITS*i + j] = rank[i] + " of " + suit[j];
            card = new CARD(suit[j], rank[i], value[i], imageArray[SUITS*i + j]);
            theDeck[SUITS*i + j] = card;
        }
    }
```

So my question is why does the card imageIcon not display? (I am getting no error messages)

Comment: I suppose `imageArray[SUITS*i + j]` is an array containing `ImageIcon`s. Are you sure it is initialized properly? And what is that `C1` variable for?

Comment: Yes, it is an array containing ImageIcon's. The C1 variable is an ImageIcon in the DECK class, it is shown above.

Comment: I edited the DECK class above to show how I initialised the Array..

Comment: You should check your `CARD` constructor then. Are you shure that the label in the constructor is initialized properly and is added to the `userPanel`? Try to draw a label with some text, not with an image. This may help you locate the mistake.

Comment: And another advice is to replace your `C1 .. C52` instantiation with a `for` loop. It will save you a lot of code. And an `arrayList` instead of an `array` would be more convinient.

Comment: Yes, label is initialised and added to userPanel. The commented out line produces the image, but not when i use the getImage() method so the problem lies there somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas. Try to debug it, check the `CARD` constructor..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found the problem. I hadn't initialized the array imageArray[] with the imageIcons properly. Silly mistake but I thought I would leave this up in case other people make this silly mistake too. :)